# associate JSON parameters and sql parameters in powershell file

Tags: json, sql-server, powershell

I have a working script to make user changes from a sql server to active directory.

I want to embed a phone modification in a json parameter.
but number construction is fixed value and variable value from sql.
Today, the hard fixed value works. But as soon as I put the parameter in the json file, it (script) no longer sees the changes on the user (without the json form, it sees the changes).

Here are the lines (edited for privacy):

ok without json:

```
$Employee.Fixe = '** ** ** ** **,' + $Employee.Poste
```

With json:

```
$Employee.Fixe = ($Params.Telephone_standard + $Employee.Poste)
```

json line:

```
"Telephone_standard": "** ** ** ** **,"
```

expected display in active directory:
** ** ** ** **,***
standard number comma(pause) internal extension number

Comment: If nothing else has changed, the implication is that `$Params.Telephone_standard` doesn't contain the value you expect it to, so you need to troubleshoot that (we can't help with that, given only the information currently in your question; consider providing more details).

Comment: We need to see actual code